# Ionic 2: ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, webpack

I'm new to Ionic. I have started project with super template. But when I try to run the app in browser. It throws an error saying:

```
ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1:1
```

I have tried putting vendor.js in index.html but that has not worked.

Here's the index.html file. I have removed vendor.js as it didn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ionic App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
        .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
    }
  </script>-->

  <link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- The bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is mainly because the project is using code splitting and webpack's code was loaded after `main.js` chunk

Comment: Can you provide more information? This error means the code hasn't loaded webpack runtime just yet but it's impossible to tell why based on the given information.

Comment: What do you mean by you've removed vendor.js? Pretty sure webpack's runtime is in there somewhere

Comment: @thangngoc89 putting it in there didn't work. It was not there previously.

Answer (score 113):

Literally just went through the same thing as you are. I added the vendor.js script BEFORE the main.js in **/src/index.html** - now it runs locally.

```
  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>

  <!-- The bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did but it didn't work. Deleted the app and now again starting the project with blank templete.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since that's the cause of the error

Comment: @VishalSingh I suspect you edited the www rather than the src version

Comment: This works for newer android versions. But when I test on my android 4.4.4 it does not work. Still the same error :(

Comment: This was the problem for me (even after reading this and insisting it wasn't). I am using Laravel and have a stack just before the closing body tag, the issue was that I was not pushing to the stack, but rather including in the section; thus it was appearing above the end-of-body-scripts.

Comment: @Christian: I have the same problem. Were you able to solve it for android 4.4.4?

Comment: @ari Yes, it was a problem with one of my 3. part plugins for cordova combine with a 3. part lib dependency which did not transpile to ES5 (from EES6)

Comment: @Christian: Many thanks. Any chance you could share what plugin and lib they were?

Comment: @ari Sorry for the late response, but it was a plugin for converting json to http query params (I think)

Comment: You save me , Thanks

Answer (score 59):

This is a breaking change in Ionic-App-Scripts

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/releases/tag/v2.0.0

src/index.html must be modified to include a new vendor script tag .

```
...
<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- all code from node_modules directory is here -->
  <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>

  <!-- The bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>

</body>
...
```

Answer (score 19):

Add `vendor.js` path within the script tag in `< your application directory > /src/index.html`

```html
<script src="build/vendor.js"></script>
```

Also make changes in `< your application directory >/src/service-worker.js` File - Include `vendor.js`  in the `precache` section:

```js
// pre-cache our key assets
self.toolbox.precache(
    [
      './build/main.js',
      './build/vendor.js',   // <===  Add vendor.js
      './build/main.css',
      './build/polyfills.js',
      'index.html',
      'manifest.json'
    ]
);
```

Comment: I did not have self.toolbox.precache(...); in /src/service-worker.js prior to this complaint about vendor.js

The update to index.htm seems to take care of the runtime error...without modifying service-worker.js

What does it mean to "pre-cache these assets" ? and does is apply to PWA deployments as well as to building for platform like Android?

Comment: very important to make sure it is here otherwise it wont work

Comment: Simple add <script src="build/vendor.js"></script> before main.js in your index.html

Answer (score 18):

I face the same issue when i started developing old ionic 2 project with ionic 3.
follow this steps works for me.
opne `src\index.html`
put this line

```
<script src="build/vendor.js"></script>
```

before

```
<script src="build/main.js"></script>
```

and after

```
<script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>
```

like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app>
  </ion-app>
  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>
  <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>  <---- here
  <!-- The bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ionic version problem bro.

check the version.

```
npm install -g ionic@v3.0.1
npm install -g ionic@v2.0.1
npm install -g ionic@v1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install -g ionic@v3.0.1
```

or

```
yarn add -g ionic@v3.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a ReactJs project when I faced this error. This could be a case of missing dependencies from `package.json` file which eventually bubbles up in the form of error reported by OP. In our case a reference to [omitJs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/omit) npm package was missing. The moment I added below line in dependencies section of `package.json` file it all started to work:

```
"dependencies": {
.....other dependencies
"omit.js": "1.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just have faced this issue, and the order of the files polyfills/vendor/main doesn't anything has to do in my case, but it was the size of the vendor.js file.

I did realize it because it works on my local machine, so, I did find that vendor.js was 5MB, so, I builded again the app using --prod parameter:

```
ionic cordova build ios --prod
```