# Upgrading the Spring Boot - Angular 2 app to Angular 8 giving blank screen

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular8

Ok, So I have this `Spring Boot - Angular2` app bundled together in a single pom file (with `maven frontend plugin`) which I want to upgrade to Angular 8.

I did all the necessary changes required and when I deploy the app to `tomcat`, the application doesn't load and all I get is a white blank screen.

I checked the console the this is the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined
at polyfills.0af4ac47d2b4b3f23f57.bundle.js:1
```

I checked for this error on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46866488/webpack-uncaught-referenceerror-webpackjsonp-is-not-defined)but couldn't find the solution. Am sure there might be some configuration issues which am not able to identify.

Here is the configuration changes I did:

Added `tsconfig.app.json`:

```
{
"extends": "../tsconfig.json",
"compilerOptions": {
"outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
"baseUrl": "./",
"module": "es2015",
"types": []
},
"exclude": [
"test.ts",
"**/*.spec.ts"
 ]
}
```

`tsconfig.spec.json`:

```
  {
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

`index.html`

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My Portal</title>
<base href="/MyPortal/">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/pb_logo_final.png">
</head>
<body>


    <app-root></app-root>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is how my pom plugins look like:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <workingDirectory>${angular.project.location}</workingDirectory>
            <installDirectory>${angular.project.nodeinstallation}</installDirectory>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <!-- It will install nodejs and npm -->
            <execution>
                <id>install node and npm</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>v10.15.3</nodeVersion>
                    <npmVersion>6.4.1</npmVersion>

                </configuration>
            </execution>

            <!-- It will execute command "npm install" inside "/e2e-angular2" directory -->
            <execution>
                <id>npm install</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>npm</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <arguments>install</arguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <!-- It will execute command "npm build" inside "/e2e-angular2" directory 
                to clean and create "/dist" directory -->
            <execution>
                <id>npm build</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>npm</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <arguments>run build</arguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

    <!-- Plugin to copy the content of /angular/dist/ directory to output 
        directory (ie/ /target/transactionManager-1.0/) -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default-copy-resources</id>
                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/</outputDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${project.basedir}/${angular.project.location}/dist</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

I looked into the page source on the browser and it loads up following scripts:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My Portal</title>
<base href="/MyPortal/">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/pb_logo_final.png">
<link href="styles.51a2f0b5202a971140a2.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/></head>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.f3fde1d9c5d2605e9d90.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.0af4ac47d2b4b3f23f57.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.ac406425285365c681b3.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I do `mvn clean install` , copy the war file in tomcat webapp and start the server. I hit `localhost:8080/MyPortal/` which ideally should open the main page of the app but shows up blank screen.

Not sure why? Have already looked into few [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50674153/after-upgrading-to-angular-6-application-shows-blank-white-screen) so this is not a duplicate.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should specify from which (current) version of Angular you are trying to upgrade to version 8.

Comment: Though the first statement says `Angular2`, still have updated the question title.

Comment: What I meant is: from which "Angular2" version, since there are versions from 2 to 8, with minor (and patch) versions in between ;) BTW, why the [angularjs] tag? I thought it was Angular 2+