# Can any one help to resolve this?? Even that i have included vendor,js file in Index.html

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, npm

On running the application i am find this error.

I have already tried with including vendor javascript in index.html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1czRx.png)

Comment: Can you show me how to your code work. Your index.html file etc ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a duplicated from this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44988493/11289490

Copying the answer from there:

> Literally just went through the same thing as you are. I added the
>   vendor.js script BEFORE the main.js in **/src/index.html** - now it
>   runs locally.
>
> ```
>   <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
>   <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>
>
>   <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>
>
>   <!-- The bundle js is generated during the build process -->
>   <script src="build/main.js"></script>
> ```